# Measure disk space of certain file types in aggregate

Tags: linux, bash, unix, diskspace

I have some files across several folders:

```
/home/d/folder1/a.txt
/home/d/folder1/b.txt
/home/d/folder1/c.mov
/home/d/folder2/a.txt
/home/d/folder2/d.mov
/home/d/folder2/folder3/f.txt
```

How can I measure the grand total amount of disk space taken up by all the .txt files in /home/d/?

I know **du will give me the total space of a given folder**, and **ls -l will give me the total space of individual files**, but what if I want to add up all the txt files and just look at the **space taken by all .txt files in one giant total** for all .txt in /home/d/ including both folder1 and folder2 and their subfolders like folder3?

Comment: If you needed it to run on HP-UX, why did you use the linux tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do it:

```sh
total=0
for file in *.txt
do
    space=$(ls -l "$file" | awk '{print $5}')
    let total+=space
done
echo $total
```

Comment: Will that find the files in subfolders folder1 and folder2?

Comment: Used a slight variation.  Removed the first -l in ls.  This still doesn't do any recursion, and it'll bomb on anything with spaces, but it is the closest thing I have. Thanks

Comment: no problem....I missed the subfolder requirement but thats easily handled by changing the for command to somethng like find . -name *.txt -exec ls  {} ;\

Comment: that ls *.txt in the for loop is redundant. just use shell expansion. --> for file in *.txt

Comment: there is a typo in your statement ennuikiller, not ';\' but 
  >find . -name "*.txt" -exec ls {} \;

Answer (score 45):

`find folder1 folder2 -iname '*.txt' -print0 | du --files0-from - -c -s | tail -1`

Comment: du doesnt appear to have a --files-from option

Comment: I meant a --files0-from option

Comment: `du --version
du (GNU coreutils) 5.93` - works on my machine.

Comment: And on my Cygwin install: du --version
du (GNU coreutils) 6.10

Comment: on my linux box I'm running coreutils 4.5.3 so it's a bit outdated

Comment: Of course, if compatibility with POSIX were required, then this wouldn't apply. But my (limited) experience with non-GNU userland has indicated that life's pretty harsh out there, best stick with GNU.

Comment: HP-UX Release 11i: November 2000... Ya, I don't have several of those options you used.  Otherwise it is a nice one line solution, just not going to work for me.

Comment: However, this number is rounded up to the nearest block for all files introducing a small error. With many small files, the error margin can be quite noticeable. For instance, du will print 4K for a file with 788 bytes of contents.

Comment: @David the question is about disk space, so rounding up to the nearest block is correct, and not a small error. But actually, it's even more than that: du, by default, will (normally) report on-disk size even for filesystems with transparent compression. Again, this is what we want. du also doesn't double-count hard-linked files.

Comment: @Barry: If it is about disk space, then you are right. If you are considering reading all those files to RAM however, the error margin still applies.

Comment: I would be surprised if the physical IO layer implements partial reads below the block granularity. It would depend on the command sequence on the wire; at the very least, I'd expect minimum of 512 bytes granularity and 4K on modern hard drives (the drives wouldn't know how to interpret finer grained addresses). I'd expect even bigger read granularity on SSDs due to how they implement writes.

Comment: The example is the best answer but has a subtle flaw: if there is a subdirectory named e.g. "my.txt" then du will total all of the files in it regardless of file name.  Adding `-type f` to the find will select only files.

Answer (score 25):

This will report disk space usage in bytes by extension:

```
find . -type f -printf "%f %s\n" |
  awk '{
      PARTSCOUNT=split( $1, FILEPARTS, "." );
      EXTENSION=PARTSCOUNT == 1 ? "NULL" : FILEPARTS[PARTSCOUNT];
      FILETYPE_MAP[EXTENSION]+=$2
    }
   END {
     for( FILETYPE in FILETYPE_MAP ) {
       print FILETYPE_MAP[FILETYPE], FILETYPE;
      }
   }' | sort -n
```

Output:

```
3250 png
30334451 mov
57725092729 m4a
69460813270 3gp
79456825676 mp3
131208301755 mp4
```

Comment: This works wonderfully.  To get human readable output, like `123GiB mp4`, pipe the output to `numfmt --field=1 --to=iec-i --format "%8f" --suffix B`.

Answer (score 16):

Simple:

```sh
du -ch *.txt
```

If you just want the total space taken to show up, then:

```sh
du -ch *.txt | tail -1
```

Comment: Try `du -ch /home/d/**/*.txt | tail -1`

Comment: @FranklinClark While that would work, it relies on `shopt -s globstar`, at least with Bash.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a way to do it (in Linux, using GNU coreutils [`du`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/du-invocation.html#du-invocation) and Bash syntax), avoiding [bad practice](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs):

```
total=0
while read -r line
do
    size=($line)
    (( total+=size ))
done < <( find . -iname "*.txt" -exec du -b {} + )
echo "$total"
```

If you want to exclude the current directory, use `-mindepth 2` with `find`.

Another version that doesn't require Bash syntax:

```
find . -iname "*.txt" -exec du -b {} + | awk '{total += $1} END {print total}'
```

Note that these won't work properly with file names which include newlines (but those with spaces will work).

Comment: As noted in its [manual](https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1/du/), POSIX `du` later removed the `-b` option, prints usage in 512-byte blocks (default) or 1-K blocks with `-k`. The `-b` option is absent from the BSD/macOS version and appears to be Linux-only. The situation for `stat` is not [much](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stat) [better](https://www.unix.com/man-page/mojave/1/stat/) (note `-c` vs. `-f` for the "format" option). My opinion is it's best to avoid `du` (or `stat`) for this, unless you only care about one OS or you're prepared to smooth over the inconsistencies among Unixes.

Comment: @TheDudeAbides: [This](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/du.html) is a better source for the information you posted. Note that it doesn't proscribe `-b` from being included in implementations of `du` and GNU continues to [include it](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/du-invocation.html#du-invocation).

Answer (score 5):

***macOS***

- use the tool `du` and the parameter `-I` to exclude all other files

***Linux***

```
-X, --exclude-from=FILE
              exclude files that match any pattern in FILE

--exclude=PATTERN
              exclude files that match PATTERN
```

Comment: I can't find any mention of -I on the [man page](https://linuxconfig.org/du-1-manual-page). Could you provide an example?

Comment: @FelixEve Please read my answer again. I think this should be clear that `-I` only exists for `du` running on macOS.

Answer (score 3):

GNU find,

```
find /home/d -type f -name "*.txt" -printf "%s\n" | awk '{s+=$0}END{print "total: "s" bytes"}'
```

Comment: BSD (macOS) `find` doesn't have a `-printf` option, so, as noted, this is a GNU/Linux-only option. If you install `findutils` with [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=library&substr=findutils) or [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/findutils), you can use `gfind` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Building on ennuikiller's, this will handle spaces in names. I needed to do this and get a little report:

find -type f -name "*.wav" | grep export | ./calc_space

```
#!/bin/bash
# calc_space
echo SPACE USED IN MEGABYTES
echo
total=0
while read FILE
do
    du -m "$FILE"
    space=$(du -m "$FILE"| awk '{print $1}')
    let total+=space
done
echo $total
```

Answer (score 2):

A one liner for those with GNU tools on bash:

```
for i in $(find . -type f | perl -ne 'print $1 if m/\.([^.\/]+)$/' | sort -u); do echo "$i"": ""$(du -hac **/*."$i" | tail -n1 | awk '{print $1;}')"; done | sort -h -k 2 -r
```

You must have extglob enabled:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

If you want dot files to work, you must run

```
shopt -s dotglob
```

Sample output:

```
d: 3.0G
swp: 1.3G
mp4: 626M
txt: 263M
pdf: 238M
ogv: 115M
i: 76M
pkl: 65M
pptx: 56M
mat: 50M
png: 29M
eps: 25M
```

etc

Comment: I dig where you're going with this, but by the time you've wrapped a `for` loop around a call to `find`, `perl`, `sort`, `du`, `tail`, `awk`, and `sort` again, it's probably time to let go of the "one-liner" badge of pride and break this over multiple lines with some backslashes. No one can admire your clever solution when most of it is buried in the right margin. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

my solution to get a total size of all text files in a given path and subdirectories (using perl oneliner)

```
find /path -iname '*.txt' | perl -lane '$sum += -s $_; END {print $sum}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use find in combination with xargs:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -print0 |xargs -0 du -ch
```

Add tail if you only want to see the grand total

```
find . -name "*.txt" -print0 |xargs -0 du -ch | tail -n1
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wanting to do this with macOS at the command line, you need a variation based on the -print0 argument instead of printf. Some of the above answers address that but this will do it comprehensively by extension:

```
    find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 stat -f "%N %i" |
  awk '{
      PARTSCOUNT=split( $1, FILEPARTS, "." );
      EXTENSION=PARTSCOUNT == 1 ? "NULL" : FILEPARTS[PARTSCOUNT];
      FILETYPE_MAP[EXTENSION]+=$2
    }
   END {
     for( FILETYPE in FILETYPE_MAP ) {
       print FILETYPE_MAP[FILETYPE], FILETYPE;
      }
   }' | sort -n
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several potential problems with the accepted answer:

1. it does not descend into subdirectories (without relying on non-standard shell features like [`globstar`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html))
2. in general, as pointed out by Dennis Williamson below, you should avoid [parsing the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

   - namely, if the user or group (columns 3 and 4) have spaces in them, column 5 will not be the file size
3. if you have a million such files, this will spawn *two* million subshells, and it'll be sloooow

As [proposed by ghostdog74](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1361832/785213), you can use the GNU-specific `-printf` option to `find` to achieve a more robust solution, avoiding all the excessive pipes, subshells, Perl, and weird `du` options:

```sh
# the '%s' format string means "the file's size"
find . -name "*.txt" -printf "%s\n" \
  | awk '{sum += $1} END{print sum " bytes"}'
```

*Yes, yes, solutions using `paste` or `bc` are also possible, but not any more straightforward.*

On macOS, you would need to use Homebrew or MacPorts to install `findutils`, and call `gfind` instead. (I *see* the "linux" tag on this question, but it's also tagged "unix".)

Without GNU `find`, you can still fall back to using `du`:

```sh
find . -name "*.txt" -exec du -k {} + \
  | awk '{kbytes+=$1} END{print kbytes " Kbytes"}'
```

…but you have to be mindful of the fact that `du`'s default output is in **512-byte blocks** for historical reasons (see the ["RATIONALE" section](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/du.1p.html#RATIONALE) of the man page), and some versions of `du` (notably, macOS's) will not even *have* an option to print sizes in bytes.

Many other fine solutions here (see [Barn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14771141/785213) in particular), but most suffer the drawback of being unnecessarily complex or depending too heavily on GNU-only features—and maybe in your environment, that's OK!

Comment: I get `find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"` on both bash and zsh

Comment: @Tun Good catch, sorry about that. A `find -exec` always needs a `{}` so it knows where to put the incoming arguments. I get lazy because this is inferred with `xargs` and GNU Parallel.